# Using ObjectAnimator to do animations in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-animation, objectanimator

How to use **ObjectAnimator** to animate the **X** property of a view, but by just setting the starting position in the xml animation file like the following:

```
<objectAnimator 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="100.0" />
```

And the final position in the layout (Since, for my case, the final position of the view will be relative to other views in the layout).
So, I can't have more precise views by doing:

```
<objectAnimator 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="100.0"
    android:valueFrom="300.0" />
```

This is easily doable by using the view animation instead of the property animation and using the **fromXDelta** property.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"/>
</set>
```

This will animate the view from 100% of the screen's width to the position being set in the layout.

Comment: i dont get your point, what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @pskink I have edited the question to be clearer. What exactly you don't get in the question?

Comment: just use your own property - call it "hiddenDroid" for example and simply create a method `setHiddenDroid(float f) { ...` and do whatever you want with your view here

Comment: I don't think you got what I mean. Because setProperty() won't work for this case

Comment: run [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/VX7eVCE3), what `setProperty` do you mean?

Comment: and, as i sad, do whatever you want with your view inside `setHiddenDroid` - for example: `v.setTranslationX(v.getWidth() * f * 0.5f)`

Comment: @pskink Thank you so much for all your answers. I will try it and get back to you

Answer (score 3):

this might help you to do the animation programmatically when you get the final position of layout:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(solution_board_layout, 
  "translationX", 0, 300);
  anim.setDuration(0);
  anim.start();
```